# ListViewWebPart in visualwebpart

Tags: list, splimitedwebpartmanager

I have visual web part,on that web part i have a text box and a button. User enters some value in text box and clicks button (which actually makes a service call). I get the data, my requirement is to show this data in a list(sharepoint list) on the same webpart.how should i do it.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the SharePoint List Web Service to insert the data into your list?

/_vti_bin/lists.asmx